# ifelse and %in% applied to rows of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Excuse my simple question, but since ifelse is vectorized, shouldn't it iterate through the rows of my dataframe?

e.g, when I try

```
   df <- data.frame(col1=c("a", "b", "c"),
                    col2=c("d", "e", "f"), 
                    col3=c("g", "h", "i"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

    ifelse('a' %in% df, 1, 0)
```

My result is 0.

Shouldn't it be 1, 0, 0?

In this case, what's the point of `ifelse`? Can I somehow use this function to iterate through my dataframe?

Comment: with `ifelse` you get what you put in, so if you enter a length 1 vector, that's what you get back

Comment: I wasn't testing length here, just inclusion...

Comment: As you suggested, you aren't iterating through your data frame. - it's a problem with using `%in%` not with using `ifelse`.

Comment: what is the correct alternative?

Comment: the data.frame is a list, so you are iterating through the elements of that list, being col1, col2, etc. so you want to operate on those elements `lapply(df, \`%in%\`, 'a')`

Comment: `ifelse` is vectorized, meaning it's made to work with **vectors** which have one dimension. A data frame has two dimensions, and that is why your try didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are attempting to iterate over rows, rather than columns:

```
apply(df,1, function(y){ ifelse('a' %in% y, 1, 0)})
```

If you are iterating over columns, then `lapply` will work:

```
lapply(df, function(y){ ifelse('a' %in% y, 1, 0)})
```

(The difference will be more obvious if you are looking for an element that doesn't have the same row-index and column-index in your data frame.)